# IE8 CSS Body background color

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I have a page that works fine in most browsers(Safari, FF, Chrome, IE9) but on IE8 it won't show the body background color. It shows the Body bgcolor as white. In the Developer Tools, I see that it is overriding all the CSS and getting some background-color:#fff from somewhere.

I have my scripts (jquery 1.6.2) just before the closing  tag as is suggested on the HTML5 Boilerplate (html5boilerpate.com) - not sure if not having the scripts in the head section causes this behaviour?

Anyone any ideas ? This is really weird.

Comment: I don't see a reason for you to use `<body bgcolor=>`

Comment: Can you post your css so we can take a look?

Comment: Please post your code, so we can see what's causing the problem. Thx.

Comment: Do you have another javascript library that is setting css, i.e. jQuery UI?

Comment: I am setting the bgcolor in css, not in body tag <code>body{ 
 font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; 
 font-size: 12px; 
 text-align: center; 
 margin: 0; 
 background: #e6e6e6; 
}</code>

Comment: Also worth mentioning I have got blueprint css files in the head section as well. No other libraries apart from jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things to try.

1. Toy with the load order of your css files. Whatever is loaded last will be the style if you don't specify `!important`
2. Inspect your rendered html for inline `<style/>` blocks as they could be causing trouble and not show up in the style tab as a specific css file.
3. When in doubt target background-color directly as background will
   sometimes be overridden by  a background-color property
   `body{background-color:#e6e6e6}`
4. If that doesnt work you could force
   override it with `body{background-color:#e6e6e6 !important}`.

Answer (score 1):

**Background color not working on Internet Explorer (IE)**

IE apply some filter before rendering web page . that's why some page colors changed .

you can add following line in your CSS file to avoid it.

```
 filter: none !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

Scanning through the blueprint css, it looks like the background color #fff is being set in two different locations: textarea and in a select box.  Try removing the background color property from textarea and see if that helps, or even better comment out the blueprint references to see if that's causing the problem.  Seems like 9 out of 10 times a property gets overridden in IE its because a third party library is assigning a diff property to the same element.